# Query to return number of most recent consecutive days

Tags: mysql, sql, query-performance

I have a table to represent the days of calendars.
I want a (Good) query (Mysql) that returns the number of the most recent consecutive days of one calendar with check = 1.

For example:

```
table "day"

+---------+------------+------+-------------+
|      id | date       | check| calendar_id |
+---------+-------------------+-------------+
|       1 | 2011-06-30 |    1 |           1 | 
|       2 | 2011-07-01 |    0 |           2 |
|       3 | 2011-07-02 |    1 |           1 |
|       4 | 2011-07-03 |    0 |           3 |
|       5 | 2011-07-10 |    1 |           1 |
|       6 | 2011-08-20 |    1 |           1 |
|       7 | 2011-08-25 |    1 |           5 |
|       8 | 2011-08-28 |    0 |           1 |
|       9 | 2011-08-29 |    1 |           1 |
|       10| 2011-08-30 |    1 |           1 |
|       11| 2011-08-31 |    1 |           1 |
+---------+-------------------+-------------+
```

For the calendar nº1, the query must return

```
+--------------------+
|      number of days|
+--------------------+
|                  3 | 
+--------------------+
```

(2011-08-29, 2011-08-30, 2011-08-31)

**This query works, but i dont know if is a good one**

```
SELECT t.*, IF((@prev - INTERVAL 1 DAY = t.d or @prev is NULL) and @c <> -1, @c := @c + 1, @c := -1) AS streak, @prev := t.d
 FROM (
    SELECT date AS d
    FROM day
    WHERE calendar_id = 1
    AND check = 1
    order by d desc
 ) AS t
 INNER JOIN (
      SELECT @prev := NULL, @c := 0
 ) AS vars
 ORDER BY streak DESC limit 1
```

Comment: On this site you have the most bestest(ever) queries.

Comment: @Gabriel, the concepts you care about is called "runs" and "gaps" and "islands" - here are [stackoverflow posts about islands and gaps in mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gaps-and-islands+mysql)

Comment: @fancyPants Look the question